# Opening a .txt for pandas with no delimiter and number of values of different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**TLDR**: How to save .txt data without delimiter in dataframe where each value array has a different length and is date depended.

---

I've got a fairly big data set saved in a .txt file with no delimiter in the following format:

```
id DateTime 4 84 464 8 64 874 5 854 652 1854 51 84 521 [. . .] 98 id DateTime 45 5 5 456 46 4 86 45 6 48 6 42 84 5 42 84 32 8 6 486 4 253 8 [. . .]
```

id and DateTime are numbers as well but ive written them in strings for readability here. 
The length between the first id DateTime combination and the next is variable and not all values start/end on the same date.

Right now what I do is use `.read_csv` whith `delimiter=" "` which results in a three column DataFrame with id, DateTime and Values all stacked upon each other:

```
id DateTime Value
10  01.01     78
10  02.01    781
10  03.01     45
[:]  
220 05.03     47
220 06.03      8
220 07.03     12
[:]
```

Then I create a dictionary for each id with the respective DateTime and their Values with `dict[id]= df["Value"][df["id"]==id]` resulting in a dictionary with keys as id.

Sadly using `.from_dict()` doesn't work here because each value list is of different length. To solve this I create a `np.zeros()` that is bigger than the biggest of the value arrays from the dictionary and save the values for each id inside a new np.array based on their DateTime. Those new arrays are then combined in a new data frame resulting in a lot of rows populated with zeros.

Desired output is:

- A DataFrame with each column representing a id and their values.
- First column as the overall Timeframe of the data set. Bascilly min(DateTime) to max(DateTime)
- Rows in a column where no values exist should be NaN

This seems to be a lot of hassle for something that is in structure so simple (see original format). Besides that, it's quite slow. There must be a way to save the data inside a DataFrame based upon the DateTime leaving unpopulated areas with NaN.

**What is a (if possible) more optimal solution for my issue?**

Comment: can you detail what the output should be

Comment: Added the desired output

Comment: just want to create a new column for each id with corresponding values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i understand this should work:

`for id in df.id.unique():
    df[str(id)] = df.id.where(df.id == id)`

Comment: Solved the issue when I changed df.id.where(..) ti df.values.where(..)!